# Magento 2 - Remove and change footer links

Tags: magento2, footer

I want to remove the default links of the luma layout and add new links. How can I do that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

"About us" link and "Customer Service" link: Static block with Identifier is "**footer_links_block**"

To remove other links, use xml file (default.xml) and add this code into < body > tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="name_of_link_block" remove="true"/>
```

**Name of link block:**

Privacy and Cookie Policy: privacy-policy-link

Search Terms: search-term-popular-link

Contact Us: contact-us-link

Advanced Search: catalog-search-advanced-link

Orders and Returns: sales-guest-form-link

To add new links to footer links, use this code:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your-link-name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Title</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path-of-your-page</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: @Magev2 What method did you use to retrieve the block names?

Comment: Same as Magento 1, the name of footer link blocks will be added in the related modules, you can find at default.xml (frontend layout) of the module. eg: contact-us-link (vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\layout\default.xml), or you can search into vendor\magento with keyword is "<referenceBlock name="footer_links">"

Comment: @Magev2 How can we do this by having the default.xml inside app/design/frontend folder? I am not interested to touch anything inside vendor folder.

Comment: You can add this code: <referenceBlock name="name_of_link_block" remove="true"/> to any default.xml file from your theme (app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_Theme/Magento_Modulename/layout/default.xml)

Comment: how can we use helper for path argument?

Comment: You can try to use your block instead of helper, change Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current to your block class, your block class need to extends from \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current, in this class, create a function name getHref() and return $this->getUrl('your_path');

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me too. Any idea how to switch the order? E.g. to display Orders and Returns before Contact us or to display the custom link as first link in the list?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to remove all the links in footer that come by default, remove the reference block.

Simply add the following link in `<Vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml` under `<body>` container

`<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>`

and in same layout file add static block so you can manage footer menu from CMS static block from magento backend

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_menu">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_menu</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now you can create a static block with identifier as `footer_menu`

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
```

to default.xml file

See here for more info http://blog.i13websolution.com/how-to-remove-footer-links-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

footers links are added from two place 
1. in cms block **footer_links_block** you can edit which will reflect in footer 
 
2. in all core module search  referenceBlock="footer_links" in xml files where ever they added links all are display in footer