# rename footer link

Tags: magento2

I'd like to rename the link 'Privacy and Cookie Policy' in the footer in the default Luma theme but can't figure out how to do it. Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

I've tried renaming the page that it points to but that isn't updating the actual footer link text.

Comment: This link may help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93628/magento-2-remove-and-change-footer-links

Comment: I've seen this link and have used the approach to add/remove footer links in the past. I guess I'll just use this method to remove the default and add a new one with the text I need. If you'd like to answer this then I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: please check below file path :- vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Answer (score 1):

Here is two solution

1) add below file default.xml in one of your module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Privacy and Cookie Policy</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>
             </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>       
    </body>
</page>
```

2) Create a theme add below file

**app/design/frontend/vendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Privacy and Cookie Policy</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>
             </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>       
    </body>
</page>
```