# How to sort footer links via XML in Magento2

Tags: magento2, xml

Referencing to this ticket: [Magento 2 - Remove and change footer links](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93628/magento-2-remove-and-change-footer-links)

I have now the question if one can change the position from the respective links without removing them and reinitiating them afterwards.

Is there any sort parameter for XML?

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="sales-guest-form-link" remove="true"/>

<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="ueber-uns">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Über uns</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">ueber-uns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="kundenservice">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Kundenservice</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer-service</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="contact-us-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Kontakt</argument>
<!--                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer-service</argument> -->
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Datenschutz</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Results in:

```
Datenschutz
Kontakt
Über uns
Kundenservice
```

on the frontend (in this order), even if I declared "Über uns" BEFORE I changed the name of the `contact-us-link` and the `privacy-policy-link`

Comment: Have you try with below code?

Comment: See my comment. It worked, but could you explain what after and before do for future visitors? Thanks!

Comment: check for more reference, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_xml-instrux_before-after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep in default.xml file like below,

Using After and Before tag of xml you can use before or after element.
`before="-"` means current block display before all other elements in its parent node.`

`after="-"` means  current block display after all other elements in its parent node.

In our case parent node is `footer_links` based on this block before and after attributes are set.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="ueber-uns" after="contact-us-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Über uns</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">ueber-uns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="kundenservice" after="ueber-uns">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Kundenservice</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer-service</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="contact-us-link" after="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Kontakt</argument>
<!--                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer-service</argument> -->
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Datenschutz</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: For future visitors of this request, could you dig a little deeper into the "after"-descriptor? That would help the community for future issues like this! However, it worked and I'll mark your reply as the right one as soon as you put in a little more information about the after-descriptor.