# Magento 1 - Add block in footer reference

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I cannot add my custom block to "footer" reference in contact page

why this works?

```
     <contacts_index_index>
        <reference name="bottom.container">
            <block type="core/template" name="myname" before="-" template="contacts/myname.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
```

but this does not works?

```
    <contacts_index_index>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="core/template" name="myname" before="-" template="contacts/myname.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
```

Comment: You want to add at starting of footer section or bottom of footer section ?

Comment: a starting footer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Magento 1.9.x then you have following block references

For Magento 2 [For M2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93628/magento-2-remove-and-change-footer-links/126956#126956)

For reference check `page.xml` of your active theme or the fallback theme.

1. `footer.before`
2. `bottom.container` (this section is the starting point of footer)
3. `before_body_end`
4. `footer.before`  to call before footer section i.e bottom of main container and above of footer

You can call your static block using widgets as well

[image: reference default]

In Block reference of widget `page footer` will call your static block in `bottom.container` section i.e starting of footer section ( you can arrange by priority as well)

```
....................
     <reference name="footer">
                <block type="core/template" name="contactFormcustom" template="contacts/custom.phtml"/>
            </reference>

            <reference name="bottom.container">
                <block type="core/template" name="contactFormcustom" template="contacts/custom2.phtml"/>
            </reference>

        </contacts_index_index>
    </layout>
```

[image: footer-reference]

```
......
      <reference name="footer.before">
                <block type="core/template" name="contactFormcustom" template="contacts/custom.phtml"/>
            </reference>
........
```

[image: footerBefore]

Comment: thanks a lot but reference name is "footer" but doesn't works. I do not want to use widget

Comment: Did you correctly add the layout file in your config.xml @Altravista

Comment: `bottom.container` is the starting point and there is no need to use before="_"

Comment: but there is no way to create a block before it? in "footer" reference?

Comment: i just tried , i posted the result, where exactly you want to call ? above the footer section

Comment: @Altravista i addedd one more reference of footer in my post `footer.before` you want to call here ?

Comment: between main content and footer

Comment: then use `footer.before` i tested it

Comment: footer.before does not show anything maybe theme override thanks a lot mark as solved

Comment: is it helped you

Comment: you can check in  `/var/www/html/magento1/app/design/frontend/activetheme/default/layout/page.xml` 
 or `/var/www/html/magento1/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`  or `/var/www/html/magento1/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` or check in admin panel setting for active theme

Comment: just do it no footer.before in base template or activate theme. only on rwd. so I cannot use it but activate theme add a lot of div before bottom.container so I cannot add a fullwidth div as I like

Comment: you can define in your active theme , though they must follow theme fallback or you can create your own custom reference

Comment: yes thanks a lot I will create my own reference between main content and footer